# IF NOT EXISTS INSERT sql statement not working c#

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to carry out an 'insert if not exists' statement, i am not receiving any errors and the row does not exist in the db, however it still will not add it. Executing a normal 'insert' works but not when the 'if  not exists' is added.

I have also tried including BEGIN & END and it doesnt work.

Where am i going wrong??

```
    string getStudentModuleId = "SELECT ModuleId FROM StudentModuleMarks WHERE Mark < 40";

    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(getStudentModuleId, MyConnection3);

    try
    {
        moduleid = (int)myCommand.ExecuteScalar();

        string addRepeat = "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM StudentModules WHERE ModuleId = @moduleid AND SchoolYear = '2018') INSERT INTO StudentModules(StudentDegreeId, ModuleId, Repeat, SchoolYear, EnrolledStatus) VALUES (1,@moduleid,1,'2018','Active')";


        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(addRepeat, MyConnection3);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@moduleid", moduleid);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
```

Comment: IF NOT EXISTS INSERT is a SQL server thing, you tagged this mysql, is there is a misunderstanding?

Comment: You are trying to execute SQL-server syntax within MySQL. IF NOT EXISTS syntax in MySQL only works in stored procedures, functions or triggers not in plain SQL.

Comment: Are you sure only 1 item is returned from your query?

Comment: command.ExecuteNonQuery(); returns an integer values which indicates the number of rows changed.  If it returns a zero then nothing changed.

Comment: Hint: Add a unique key on ModuleId, SchoolYear   that also would disallow insert into the table if there is a moduleid with that same schoolyear. That is what you are checking with `IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM StudentModules WHERE ModuleId = @moduleid AND SchoolYear = '2018')`

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using sql server, For MySQL, you can follow this technique to insert record if it doesn't exist :

```
INSERT INTO StudentModules(StudentDegreeId, ModuleId, Repeat, SchoolYear, EnrolledStatus) 
    select 1,@moduleid, 1, '2018', 'Active' from dual 
        where NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM StudentModules WHERE ModuleId = @moduleid AND SchoolYear = '2018')
```

Please note that, in MySQL, you don't really need to have a table called [**dual**](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/sql-dual-table.php) to exist: it is a special table-name that can be used to select anything from it. And it will output a single record always with a `SELECT` query like above.

Comment: This could work or you end up with multiple inserted records with the same values..

Comment: The select query will produce single record as i described and i think the OP already have condition to avoid duplicate insertion in his table.

Comment: Didn't work, i removed the try & catch statements and it works now. thanks everyone

Comment: `i removed the try & catch statements and it works now`! Do you mean `try..catch` block was the problem in your code?

Comment: yeah i just removed them

Comment: That's impossible!!! `Try ... Catch` block can't be a problem, it is used to identify problems. Surely you have problem somewhere in your code.